# Ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' не могу понять, почему?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'  не могу понять, почему? Помогите, пожалуйста, мне срочно нужно.

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
soup = soup.find('img',class_='icon-btn').find_all('onclick').text[k]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все потому что вы не можете использовать метод `.find_all()` в методе `.find()`, а так же у вас имя переменной объекта соупа точно такое же как и при поиске элемента вам нужно делать наоборот, примерно вот так:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
soupItem = soup.find_all('img',class_='icon-btn')
for items in soupItem:
    item = items.find('onclick').text[k]
    print(item)
```

Грубо говоря вы для начала обнаруживаете все объекта класса **icon-btn**, потом в цикле проходитесь по ним и забираете нужный вам элемент **onclick**, и делаете с ним уже все что вам только угодно, выводите, сохраняете и тд